# Hourly measurements with gaps in timestamp: assign the missing records to 0 values

Tags: tableau-api

I have a database table with columns (timestamp, value). The timestamp is always rounded to an hour. Sometimes there are gaps between timestamps:

```
timestamp              value
--------------------   ---------
Aug,13 2014 21:00:00     52
Aug,13 2014 22:00:00     51
Aug,13 2014 23:00:00     47
Aug,14 2014 01:00:00     28
Aug,14 2014 02:00:00     31
Aug,14 2014 08:00:00     32
```

I would like to create a line plot where for the missing hours the displayed values will be  0.

My attempts:

1) Treat the timestamp (X-axis) as a discrete. Issue: the gaps are ignored and the X-axis become non-uniform.

I think if I knew how to assign the value for missing timestamps to 0 then it will solve the problem because the X-axis will be uniform.

2) Treat the timestamp (X-axis) as a continuous to make X-axis uniform.

Issue: the gaps in timestamps are ignored and I do not know how to fill it with 0 values.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things you need to do.

1. Show Missing columns

   Enable **Analysis > Table Layout > Show Empty Columns**. This will show the gaps.

[image]

2. Show 0 for the Gap.

   Add a ZN infront of your aggregation. Eg:ZN(SUM([Value]))

[image]

Please note that I am using continuous hour for my timestamp which is then converted to discrete.